# How can I find out who wrote a certain section of an article in Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

Version control systems typically call this feature "blaming someone". For each line, it shows you who modified it and when.

**Update:**  I'm looking for a solution for articles with thousands of edits as well (i.e. navigating the version history and checking each one is not practical).

Comment: Specific instructions for using WikiBlame (to find out who wrote a specific phrase) can be found here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35906/find-when-a-phrase-was-added-to-a-wikipedia-page/35914#35914

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the `View History` link for an article you can see the list of changes made to the article, on what date, and by whom. A short summary of the change description is also displayed. You can then click the `Compare selected version` button to compare text.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a *Blame* feature that lets you directly see who made the changes to a particular line or sentence or paragraph.

EDIT: You may want to check out [Greg Hewill's site](http://ghewgill.livejournal.com/118086.html), he (apparently) is working on just such a blame feature.

Comment: This is simple for short articles. However, when you have an article with hundreds or thousands of edits, it becomes much harder. I'm looking for the opposite. You give a line and it tells you the user.

Comment: That link you posted is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad you found what you needed :D

Answer (score 12):

Use http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php?lang=en which allows searching of revisions on Wikipedia.

Comment: I tried it, and it seems to be a stinker.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked just fine. Here are specific instructions for using it: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35914/20087

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to export the article history, and then process the revisions using a local tool like `git blame`. This could be done using a script.

To export the article history, [use `Special:Export`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aExport), specifically: [`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&history=1&action=submit&pages=Blinkenlights`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aExport&history=1&action=submit&pages=Blinkenlights).

To generate the blame, first add the revisions to a temporary git repository (shown in Python 3):

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as repo:
    os.chdir(repo.name)
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'init'])
```

Then download the exported history XML, parse it with something like `lxml.etree`, and loop over the revisions (xpath `//revision`). For each revision, write the text to a file (say `article.wiki`), read the author, and run

```
subprocess.check_call(['git', 'commit', '-a', '-m', 'blah', '--author=' + str(author)])
```

After all revisions are added to the repo, run `git blame article.wiki` to see the author of each line.

Note: `Special:Export` might restrict the number of revisions exported, so in pages with long history you might have to fetch the XML multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by clicking `"View History"` located in the upper right corner of every wikipedia article.  There you will find a list of the revisions of an article.  If you want to specifically was committed by each user, you can click `"cur"` next to each revision and wikipedia will highlight what was changed.

Comment: I updated the question which explains why this method is no good for articles with thousands of versions.

Comment: It appears that OpenBSDWiki's answer is correct then.  Is that not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

- The **[Who Wrote That? Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/who-wrote-that/ekkbnedhfelfaidbpaedaecjiokkionn)** is the best/easiest tool for finding who wrote the latest revision of visible text.
- Alternatively, you can look up [Authorship percentages in XTools](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/authorship/en.wikipedia.org/Webb%27s%20First%20Deep%20Field/) for a general sense of who "wrote" the current article. Both this and Who Wrote That? are powered by [wikiwho](https://www.f-squared.org/wikiwho/).
- [WikiBlame](http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php?lang=en) is clunky and more for power-editors but will hunt for the diff of when text was added or removed. Just need to enter the page name and the specific search text.