# Find when a phrase was added to a Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, version-control

Is there any way to find when a specific word or phrase was added to a Wikipedia page?  I want to find a way to determine the first revision that contains a match.

For example, the first occurrence of `<ref>webapps.stackexchange.com</ref>` in a page's revision history.

Manually searching through a page's revision history would be extremely time-consuming so I'm looking for an automated solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### WikiBlame

[WikiBlame](https://www.ramselehof.de/wikipedia/wikiblame.php) is an online PHP-based tool that does exactly that, allowing you to find when a specific word or phrase was added to a Wikipedia page.

In the search options, you specify a Wikipedia page by name or URL as well as the text you want to find, and it will return the revision(s) where the text was added. [WikiBlame](https://www.ramselehof.de/wikipedia/wikiblame.php) includes many additional search parameters, and also supports searching other projects such as [Wikisource](https://wikisource.org/), [Wikimedia](https://www.wikimedia.org/), and [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/).

<sub>**WikiBlame's Search Interface**</sub>
[image: WikiBlame's Search GUI]

### Wikipedia Pages Link to WikiBlame

Wikipedia pages include a direct pre-populated link on their **Revision history** tab that includes the referring Wikipedia page's name and language. On English pages, the link is found under **External tools:** [Find addition/removal](https://www.ramselehof.de/wikipedia/wikiblame.php).  Wikipedia pages in other languages have a translated variation.  For example,

- French [fr] - **Outils externes et statistiques:** [Rechercher l'auteur d'un passage de l'article](http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php?user_lang=fr&lang=fr&project=wikipedia&article=Stack_Exchange_Network)
- Spanish [es] - **Contribuciones:** [Búsqueda en el historial](https://www.ramselehof.de/wikipedia/wikiblame.php?project=wikipedia&user_lang=es&lang=es&article=Stack_Exchange)
- Chinese (Simplified) [zh] - **外部工具:** [搜索编辑历史](https://blame.toolforge.org/wikiblame.php?article=Stack%20Exchange&lang=zh&user_lang=zh-hans)

<sub>**WikiBlame links on Wikipedia's 'Revision history' pages [en, fr, es, zh]**</sub>
[image: Slide show alternating between English, Spanish, French and Chinese versions of a page with an arrow pointing to each language's link]

#### Additional Resources

- [WikiBlame's Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Flominator/WikiBlame)
- [WikiBlame Github Project Repository (Open Source GNU GPL v.3)](https://github.com/FlominatorTM/wikiblame)
- [WikiBlame Mirror on Toolforge](https://blame.toolforge.org/wikiblame.php)

Comment: I don't have it  on the English Wikipedia :(.

Comment: @КоеКто see the updated answer with notes on how to find it. Please flag my comment as "no longer needed once you've seen it."

Comment: @Blindspots I can find External Tool section only on page's Page Information special page.

Comment: @КоеКто you are correct when viewing the mobile version of Wikipedia (even when viewed in Desktop mode). Good catch!  If you view the normal version of Wikipedia ([https://en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/) instead of [https://en.m.wikipedia.org](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/)) it matches the answer. I'll try to add this info into the answer when I have time to improve it if someone else doesn't get to it first. Appreciate you following up as I wasn't aware and other people might also get confused. 

Answer (score 1):

> Wikimedia provides an [XML dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) of the complete revision history for
>   all Wikipedia articles. This dataset contains a version of that data
>   from April, 2010. This dataset does not contain the full text of the
>   revisions, but rather just the meta information about the revisions,
>   including things like language, timestamp, article and the like.

On every page, in the top-right corner there is a `History` button that takes you to the revision history for that page.

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia Revision History](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-wikipedia)